# Canvas drawing getting blur

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

Somehow the canvas drawing is getting blur when attached under tabs of jquery ui.
Can anybody help me to figure out why canvas drawing is getting blur?

problem seems to be in this section

```
  .ui-tabs-panel {
    height:500px; }
  #chartCanvas-1,#crossCanvas-1{

    position:absolute; top:50px; left:0px;
    /*border:1px solid blue;
    width:500px;
    height:400px;*/
  }
/*#crossCanvas-1{ border:1.5px solid green;}
#chartCanvas-1{ border:1px solid red;}*/
```

Using jquery 1.8.3
Using jquery ui and css

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
<title> Create dynamic Tabs using jQuery and css</title>
<script  type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  $(function() {
    var tabTitle = $( "#tab_title" ),
      tabContent = $( "#tab_content" ),
      tabTemplate = "<li><a href='#{href}'>#{label}</a> <span class='ui-icon ui-icon-close'>Remove Tab</span></li>",
      tabCounter = 2;

    var tabs = $( "#tabs" ).tabs();

    // modal dialog init: custom buttons and a "close" callback reseting the form inside
    var dialog = $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        Add: function() {
          addTab();
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        },
        Cancel: function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
      },
      close: function() {
        form[ 0 ].reset();
      }
    });

    // addTab form: calls addTab function on submit and closes the dialog
    var form = dialog.find( "form" ).submit(function( event ) {
      addTab();
      dialog.dialog( "close" );
      event.preventDefault();
    });

    // actual addTab function: adds new tab using the input from the form above
    function addTab() {
      var label = tabTitle.val() || "Tab " + tabCounter,
        id = "tabs-" + tabCounter,
        chartCanvas_id = "chartCanvas-" + tabCounter,
        crossCanvas_id = "crossCanvas-" + tabCounter,
        li = $( tabTemplate.replace( /#\{href\}/g, "#" + id ).replace( /#\{label\}/g, label ) ),
        tabContentHtml = tabContent.val() || "Tab " + tabCounter + " content.";

      tabs.find( ".ui-tabs-nav" ).append( li );      
      tabs.append( "<div id='" + id + "'><canvas id='"+chartCanvas_id+  "'></canvas><canvas id='"+crossCanvas_id+  "'></canvas></div>" );
      tabs.tabs( "refresh" );
      tabCounter++;
    }

    // addTab button: just opens the dialog
    $( "#add_tab" )
      .button()
      .click(function() {
        dialog.dialog( "open" );
      });

    // close icon: removing the tab on click
    $( "#tabs span.ui-icon-close" ).live( "click", function() {
      var panelId = $( this ).closest( "li" ).attr( "aria-controls" );
      if( panelId !== "tabs-1")
      {
            panelId = $( this ).closest( "li" ).remove().attr( "aria-controls" );
          $( "#" + panelId ).remove();
          tabs.tabs( "refresh" );
      }

      });

      var canvas=document.getElementById("chartCanvas-1");
      var context=canvas.getContext("2d");
      var canvasOffset=$("#chartCanvas-1").offset();
      /*var canvasTemp=document.getElementById("crossCanvas-1");
      var ctxTemp=canvasTemp.getContext("2d");
      var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
      var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;*/
      context.beginPath();
      context.moveTo(10, 10);
      context.lineTo(40,30);
      context.stroke();
      context.closePath();
      /*ctxTemp.beginPath();
      ctxTemp.moveTo(0, 0);
      ctxTemp.lineTo(40,50);
      ctxTemp.stroke();
      ctxTemp.closePath();          */


  });
  </script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.css">

<style type="text/css">
  #dialog label, #dialog input { display:block; }
  #dialog label { margin-top: 0.5em; }
  #dialog input, #dialog textarea { width: 95%; }
  #tabs { margin-top: 0.7em; height: 600px;}

  #tabs li .ui-icon-close { float: left; margin: 0.4em 0.2em 0 0; cursor: pointer; }
  #add_tab { cursor: pointer; }
  .ui-tabs-panel {
    height:500px; }
  #chartCanvas-1,#crossCanvas-1{

    position:absolute; top:50px; left:0px;
    /*border:1px solid blue;
    width:500px;
    height:400px;*/
  }
/*#crossCanvas-1{ border:1.5px solid green;}
#chartCanvas-1{ border:1px solid red;}*/
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="dialog" title="Tab data">
  <form>
    <fieldset class="ui-helper-reset">
      <label for="tab_title">Title</label>
      <input type="text" name="tab_title" id="tab_title" value="" class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
      <label for="tab_content">Content</label>
      <textarea name="tab_content" id="tab_content" class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"></textarea>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>

<button id="add_tab">Add Tab</button>

<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Default</a> <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-close">Remove Tab</span></li>        
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <canvas id="chartCanvas-1" style="width: 600px; height: 400px"></canvas>
    <!-- <canvas id="crossCanvas-1" style="width: 600px; height: 400px"></canvas> -->
  </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Regards,
SK

Comment: How about create a jsfiddle, that will reproduce the issue, tell where the jsfiddle's result dose not met your expect?

Comment: Drawing on a smaller resolution or page is zoomed in

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/x2y2z2xyz3/aw5ggpy9/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the reson it's blurred is becuase of your CSS for the canvas, in the canvas tag.

```
<canvas id="chartCanvas-1" style="width: 600px; height: 400px"></canvas>
```

The standard size for a canvas is 300x150 pixels and changing the width and height with CSS will scale the canvas. To change the size of the canvas, instead do it in the JavaSCript code

```
canvas.width = 600;
canvas.height = 400;
```

And remove the style from your canvas tag in your HTML code

```
<canvas id="chartCanvas-1"></canvas>
```